# Array Empty After Fetch() and array.push()

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

I have a fetch call to an API that iterates over the returned JSON using callbacks and then I want to output the result into the console. The issue is that I feel like even though this should be doing it asynchronously, I am using the then() call, which I was under the impression it would wait for the return and print out properly. But on the first call, it prints out an empty array in the console, then on the second button press it logs the array correctly.

```js
function getPrice() {
  var valueArray = [];

  var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol_input").value;
  var url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + symbol + "/chart"
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(function(res) {
      res.forEach(element => {
        valueArray.push(element);
      });
    })
    .then(console.log(valueArray))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

```html
<input type="input" id="symbol_input">
<button id="priceButton" onclick="getPrice()">Get Price</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.then` accepts a *function* as a parameter, not a plain statement like `.then(console.log(valueArray))`. Done like that, the `console.log` will execute *immediately* (before the `fetch` completes).

Use a function instead. (Example input to use: "abc")

```js
function getPrice() {
  var valueArray = [];

  var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol_input").value;
  var url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + symbol + "/chart"
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(function(res) {
      res.forEach(element => {
        valueArray.push(element);
      });
    })
    .then(() => console.log(valueArray))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

```html
<input type="input" id="symbol_input">
<button id="priceButton" onclick="getPrice()">Get Price</button>
```